# PHP IF body and ELSE body both executing

Tags: php, if-statement

This is a very strange problem.. I've looked all around for a solution.. 
Here is my code. It is part of an account settings page on a website I am creating. The code has to do with the user changing his first name:

```
// if there are post vars, user has changed something
if($_POST) {
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);

    if(strlen($firstname) < 2 || strlen($firstname) > 15) {
        $msg = "<span class='errmsg'>Could not complete your request. First name must be between 2 and 15 characters.</span>";
    }
    else {
        // connect to db
        require_once('modules/config.php');

        // update table
        $query = sprintf("UPDATE Users SET FirstName = '%s' WHERE Email = '%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email']));
        mysql_query($query);

        // set success message
        $msg = "<span class='sucmsg'>First name successfully changed.</span>";

        // reset the firstname session var
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    }
}
    }
```

EDIT: Added the closing brace that Dagon mentioned.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: Just looking at it, it appears as if you're missing a trailing `}` for the first `if()`.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add in the closing }. That's not the issue I'm experiencing. The $msg is being set to the value in the if body, but the database is still being updated for some reason..

Comment: As  far as I see, no error in code...

Comment: This might sound weird but try replacing your "||" with the "or" keyword. I once had a problem with that and for some reason it solved it.

Comment: I tried replacing || with 'or' but the problem persisted :/

Comment: Maybe the contents of modules/config.php?

Comment: Contents of modules/config.php:`<?php
$con = mysql_connect('bjusoscom1.ipagemysql.com', 'bjusoscom1', 'xxxxxxxxxxx'); 
mysql_select_db('bjusos');
?>`

Comment: This is weird, but the code runs as expected on my local development server (a Xampp server) and is only buggy on the live server (iPage).. Both php files are exactly the same..

Comment: Probably the contents of config.php since the include is done before the script is executed. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think require_once includes the file content BEFORE execution. There might be a problem with that.

Comment: I can't comment much more. Maybe iPage is using some odd PHP module such as mod_layout which is conflicting.

Comment: I figured out that the database is not being updated, only the session variable is being changed. But it is not the line `$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;` that is doing it. I've tried commenting out that line and the session variable still changes..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `}` at the end.

`else {`

is actually closing:

`if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {`

instead of

`if(strlen($firstname) < 2 || strlen($firstname) > 15) {`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will solve your problem, try it...

```
 if(in_array(strlen($firstname), range(2, 15)))
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked the same as it has been doing: Works fine on Xampp dev server and is broken on iPage..